# How to get request headers rather than response headers using Python Requests

Tags: python, xmlhttprequest, python-requests

How can I grab the request headers for an XHR requests using Python Requests module? Using the following code seems to return the response headers:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://www.whoscored.com/tournamentsfeed/12496/Fixtures/?d=2015W50&isAggregate=false')
headers = r.headers
print headers
```

This returns an object that looks like this:

```
{'content-length': '624', 'content-encoding': 'gzip', 'expires': '-1', 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'server': 'Microsoft-IIS/8.0', 'pragma': 'no-cache', 'cache-control': 'no-cache', 'date': 'Tue, 15 Dec 2015 14:41:34 GMT', 'x-powered-by': 'ASP.NET', 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'}
```

However, when I look in Chrome developer tools the request header looks like this:

```
Host: www.whoscored.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/plain, */*; q=0.01
Model-Last-Mode: W50hFYr7jwZWt40WUb9udPVFxmB6g9yct204X0/gmf4=
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://www.whoscored.com/Regions/252/Tournaments/2/England-Premier-League
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cookie: __gads=ID=d09f8c0cdc1a4258:T=1449875272:S=ALNI_MbTPDtXiIlHK49F4FOqdDap__pfCA; nlsnocrvu=1; OX_plg=swf|shk|pm; _ga=GA1.3.578623339.1449875271; _gat=1; _ga=GA1.2.578623339.1449875271
```

Can anyone assist?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for request headers like this

```
r.request.headers
```

That would give you something like

```
{'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.7.0 CPython/2.7.10 Darwin/15.0.0'}
```

For obvious reasons it won't be the same as you see in the Chrome developer tools, because the browser adds its own headers which the `requests` module doesn't.

```
GET /tournamentsfeed/12496/Fixtures/?d=2015W50&isAggregate=false HTTP/1.1
Host: www.whoscored.com
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6
Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.788154924.1450195026; _gat_as25n45=1
```

To get these headers you need to run some js code to pull the headers.

Comment: hi, thanks for replying. do you have any example code that would do this?

Comment: @Abhinav, the answer you posted link to is about response headers, not request ones